# Do I use a dependent or independent T-Test with this experimental setup?

Tags: t-test, independence

I've run an experiment where users had to work with 2 systems (one after the other), and grade them on usability. This results in a score 0-100 of both systems. 50% of participants used system 1 first and then switched to system 2, and the other 50% used system 2 first and then switched to 1 (randomized).

Do I use a dependent T-Test (because a participant uses both system 1 and 2), or must I use an independent T-Test here?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly neither; if order matters you want to also account for which one was presented first.

If you don't believe in an order effect* you might do a paired t-test, but if the scores are likely to be skew then you might want to consider something else (perhaps a permutation test, depending on what kind of inferential statements you want to be able to make).

*(in which case why did you need to attempt to control for it?)

If you do believe in the reasonably likely existence of an order effect (consistently with your controlling for it), then you would need something more than a t-test. It may be possible to do what you need with regression, for example.